# Can't get minimal ASP .NET Core 3.1 WebSocket example to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

I'm trying to migrate my old WebSocket server to ASP.NET Core 3.1. Problem is that even minimum example is not working - when connecting server via web socket on debug, no code is executed and websocket connect timeouts.

I just create empty ASP.NET Core 3.1 project from template and add:
- app.UseWebSockets();
- app.Use - see code below
I also comment out default Routing and UseEndpoints.

Startup code:

```
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseWebSockets();

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

                    await Echo(context, webSocket);
                }
                else
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not a websocket request");
                    //context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                }
            });

            //app.UseRouting();
            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            //    {
            //        //int a = 0;
            //        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //    });
            //});
        }

        private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
            {
                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

                result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            }
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

When I connect to this server via browser/normal http request, I get correct response "Not a websocket request". But when I try to connect via WebSocket, no user code is hit. In ASP .NET Core 2.2 code works.

Do I have to specify somewhere to accept WebSockets?

Comment: `when I try to connect via WebSocket, no user code is hit` Based on my test, [WebSockets supports well in .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Please share the code snippet you are using to establish connection and exchange message, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: @FeiHan I was trying to make minimal example based on that doc. When I download sample referenced from that document it works. But that is Asp Net Core 2.x. I'm connecting to my server via Firefox Simple WebSocket client or simple c# websocket-sharp code. Both works with 2.x sample.

Comment: Did [a test using Firefix Simple WebSocket Client plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYa8P.png), and which works well. I'd like to know which one you try to connect, `ws://` or `wss://`?

Comment: That's it! Using wss:// and everything works! Property in launchSettings.json - "sslPort": decides whenever secure websocket connection is REQUIRED ("Configure for HTTPS" checkbox when creating a new project)

Comment: Glad to hear the issue has been solved. Before we start to establish connection(s), we should check the server URL and port first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That's it! Using wss:// and everything works!

As I mentioned, [WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.0) supports well in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and 3.1.

Besides, as we discussed in comments, we should check the server URL and port before we start to establish connection(s).

*Using wss://*

[image]

*Using ws://*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer for this particular case.
But it happened to me to be unable to connect to wss after refactoring.
Try a GET request to your websoket endpoint. It might reveal that you are **missing dependencies** for injection in your constructor, like a repository or a service.